# Chat not opening in SO

Tags: support, bug, chat, accounts

The chat option hasn't been working for a lot of time. I am trying to go to the SO chat for a few months now, it isn't working yet. There is some problem. Fix required.

[image: Chat not working]

Comment: Looks like an account merge went wrong. Was this account yours: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5831063/coder-dude-twodee  that one does work but doesn't have a parent user and [this url](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/6109408) leads also to an error page for me.

Comment: Have you ever deleted your Stack Overflow account?

Comment: That account doesn't exist anymore, yes.